# How to find a very low U-value replacement window for a bathroom?

Tags: windows, energy-efficiency, replacement, r-value, u-value

I found 0.27 for a Pella 250 series at Lowe's.  I would like to find a window with a lower U-value.  How do I go about that?

Comment: See your other question about U-values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pushed the big box salesman to (a) give me the U-values for the windows I was considering, and (b) play with the parameters in the ordering software, to see what added features did to the U-value.  I found out that Pella 350 with foam insulation in the frame, and triple pane, got us down to 0.17.  Which is what I want for the bathroom.

I was not able to get much in the way of detailed information from the Pella salesman.

I bought the big box (Lowe's) Pella windows.